# Click to show CSS tooltip

Tags: html, css, button, tooltip

I am new to working with CSS and HTML I have been trying to create a tool tip using CSS and HTML so Far has been successful. But now want to know if possible how to make this tooltip only Appear when clicked on. And disappear when clicked again. 
Below is the HTML code i have used. 
If someone could suggest some CSS that enables me to create the desired outcome that would be brilliant

HTML

class='tooltips' style ='color:#585858; text             decoration:none;'> desktop NG     information

Thanks in advance

Comment: OP, please edit your question with the full code

Comment: So what do you have to click on so it appears? You can't click on the tooltip if it isn't already there. I think that you have to use javascript for that.

Comment: i think this link might help you http://jsfiddle.net/GQE4k/1/

Comment: .fadeToggle(); would have been much more smart since you already use jQuery

Comment: read this article http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/17/css-click-events/

Comment: Going off of @Rohit Batham's answer (can't add as a comment since my rep is too low), if you want to have it as a persistent tooltip when you click, use the `focus` selector instead of active.

Answer (score 6):

To toggle a tooltip you can use the :checked pseudo class of a checkbox.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip span {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 10em;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: -1em;
  left:  100%;
  margin-left:1em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.tooltip span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
.tooltip input {
  display:none;
}
.tooltip input:checked+span {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <label class="tooltip">world<input type="checkbox"><span>and this is the tooltip text displayed on click.</span></label>! I am greeting you.<p>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code

```
<a href="#" title="Sample tooltip" class="tooltip">Link</a>
```

CSS Code

```
.tooltip{display:inline;position:relative}
.tooltip:hover{text-decoration:none}

.tooltip:hover:after{
   background:#111;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
   border-radius:5px;
   bottom:18px;
   color:#fff;
   content:attr(title);
   display:block;
   left:50%;
   padding:5px 15px;
   position:absolute;
   white-space:nowrap;
   z-index:98
  }
.tooltip:hover:before{
    border:solid;
    border-color:#111 transparent;
    border-width:6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom:12px;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:75%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99
   }
```

Try this will work properly and onlcik event doesn't support in css.

Comment: _"onlcik event doesn't support in css."_ I think you forgot `:active` pseudo class ;)

Comment: If you want to use active: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7GM6/1/
You have to hold your mouse button on that hyperlink

Comment: @Bluedayz I tried your fiddle, but tooltip only appears when you click on the link and then dissapears automatically.. how can be fixed that?

Comment: I tried it via  jsfiddle.net/Z7GM6, but the title also appears after a second.  I switched the attribute to be "tip" and content to "attr(tip)", is there a better option?